# Customise the theme and button colors of Sharepoint communication site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have started to create a Sharepoint site in Sharepoint ins office 365 and have selected a communication site as it is going to be about our company's services.

I want to use our company's branding on the site by speicifying the color of the buttons and other parts such as the color of the band which says Sharepoint along the top of the site.  How can I do this?

I can see I can change theme colors in change look but it only gives me set combinations and none of the combinations match the colors I want to use and when I click on customise it only gives a limited number of colors and none are close to the colors I want to use.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could use online Theme Generator tool to define your new custom themes: https://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr-deploy-site/refs/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html

Then use powershell `Add-SPOTheme` to create a new custom theme, or overwrites an existing theme to modify its settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Add-SPOTheme?view=sharepoint-ps

Please refer to this article for more about site theming:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview